# How to return every value from my for loop while using formatting

Tags: python

I am currently stuck on trying to output some data and I hope someone can help me.

I made a small example to illustrate what I fail to do:

```
a = [5, 3, 8, 9]

def function_name(list):
    number = 0
    for i in list:
        number = i + 5
    return 'number = %d' % number
```

Right now my output only is 'number = 14' while I am trying to get the output (below each other): 'n = 10' 'n = 8' etc.

Is there a possibility to do so? I realize that I am overwriting my number variable, but I don't know how else to do this.

Comment: you want a loop and pass one element at a time or return the entire list from the function. Right now you are calling the funtion once which is returning only one element. Dont use `list` as variable name

Comment: That return statement is not inside the loop. Is that your intention? [Edit] the question and make it clear what you want to do, show what you have tried, and tell us the results you get.

Answer (score 1):

The conventional approach to returning multiple values from a function is to create a list, which you append your values to, and which you return after the loop.

```
a = [5, 3, 8, 9]

def function_name(list):
    number = 0
    results = []
    for i in list:
        number = i + 5
        results.append('number = %d' % number)
    return results

print(function_name(a))
```

This will give you the output `['number = 10', 'number = 8', 'number = 13', 'number = 14']`. If you want all of these on separate lines, without the quote marks or brackets, you might use `str.join` to merge them into one list delimited by newlines.

```
print("\n".join(function_name(a)))
```

... Or, replace `return results` with:

```
return "\n".join(results)
```

Depending on whether it makes sense to perform this operation *outside* of the function, or inside it. Both work perfectly well, but one will make more sense conceptually depending on the function's purpose.

---

It is also possible to do this without accumulating a list, by using `yield` instead of return. `yield` behaves something like `return`, except it can be executed multiple times within a function without terminating it. This turns the function into a generator. Fortunately for us, `str.join` happily accepts generators as an argument.

```
a = [5, 3, 8, 9]

def function_name(list):
    number = 0
    for i in list:
        number = i + 5
        yield 'number = %d' % number

print("\n".join(function_name(a)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to print inside the loop like so:

```
def function_name(lst): 
    number = 0 
    for i in lst: 
        number = i + 5 
        print('number = %d' % number)

a = [5, 3, 8, 9]
function_name(a)

# number = 10
# number = 8                                                    
# number = 13                                                 
# number = 14
```

What you do is you return from function at the end of loop, so you are left only with the last value.

---

If you need to persist with `return`, you could do:

```
def function_name(lst): 
    number, lis = 0, []
    for i in lst: 
        lis.append(i + 5)
    return lis

a = [5, 3, 8, 9]
for number in function_name(a):
    print('number = %d' % number)
```

Okay, now you add items to list in the loop and return the list at the end. At where the function is called, we iterate through the returned list and display like previously done.

Comment: I managed to do that, but in this case I need the values for another function. So, instead of printing I would like to return the values.

Answer (score 0):

With the current implementation you are returning the last_element which is `9` and adding `5` to it will return `14`

Either loop through the list

```
a = [5, 3, 8, 9]

def add_5(element):
    return element +5

for i in a:
    print(add_5(i))
```

Or return the entire list from function

```
a = [5, 3, 8, 9]

def add_5_on_list(l):
    res=[]
    for i in l:
        res.append(i+5)
    return res

print(add_5_on_list(a))
```